# State change is not retained for string property in immer produce

Tags: reactjs, immer.js

I have passed the state `calculationResultsSw` to the function below.

```
const addUserInputUsContentSw = (
calculationResultsSw: any,
id: string,
productId: string,
productNo: string,    
addUscAgreements: any,
onSuccess: () => void,
successNotification?: INotification,
failureNotification?: INotification) => {    
console.log("Inside Add User Input Us Content: CalculationResultsSw");
console.log(calculationResultsSw);

var calculatedAgreements = [];

calculatedAgreements = addUscAgreements.filter((a:any) => a.boQItem.id == productId);    

post<ISwCalculationResult>(
  `exportRequest/${id}/adduserconinputsw`,
  {
    productId,
    productNo,
    calculatedAgreements,
    isCalculated: "false"
  },
  (data: ISwCalculationResult) => {          
      setCalculationResultsSw(produce((draftState: any) =>{              
          var indices: any = [];            
          draftState.sw.agreements.forEach(function(value:any,pos: number){
            if(value.boQItem.id == productId)
            {
              indices.push(pos);
            }
          });
            for(var index = indices.length-1;index>=0;index--)
            {
              draftState.sw.agreements.splice(indices[index],1);
            }   
            draftState.sw.agreements.push(...data.sw.agreements);  
            draftState.sw.agreements.sort(comparesrlorder);
            draftState.sw.agreements.sort(compare);          
      },calculationResultsSw));
    }  
    onSuccess && onSuccess();
  },
  successNotification,
  failureNotification
);
};
```

The first `console.log` statement shows that I get two agreements.
[image: Two AgreementRows]

First product has `isVendorSelectionDone:"1"` and one `agreementRow`

[image: Agreement]

while the second product has `isVendorSelectionDone:"1"` and zero `agreementRow`

[image: Agreement2]

The Post request Api body has agreements pertaining to a particular product. The response contains the agreements updated pertaining to the requested product.
Hence after Api call I'm trying to remove the old agreements pertaining to the requested product and insert a new agreement received from the Api call.

As the first product is not the requested product, I expect that the first agreement has the same value for properties `isVendorSelectionDone:"1" and` agreementRows```.

But after the `setCalculationResults`, I see the first agreement has value
`isVendorSelectionDone:"0"` and has one `agreementRow`. The agreementRow is updated but the `isVendorSelectionDone` is not retained.

[image: After SetCalculationResults]